# c++ Expression: string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, expression

When I try debugging the code, it runs into the debugging error "c++ Expression: string subscript out of range"
Pretty sure the problem was brought while calling setCode().
How do I fix the code inside setCode()?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class test
{
    private:
        string code;
        int digit;

    public:
        //constructor
        test(): code(""), digit(0) { }

        //copy constructor
        test(const test &other):
        digit(other.digit)
        { 
            for(unsigned int i=0; i < code.length(); i++)   
                code[digit] = other.code[digit];
        }

        //set up the private values 
        void setCode(const string &temp, const int num);
        void setDigit(const int &num);

        //return the value of the pointer character 
        const string &getCode() const;
        const unsigned int getDigit() const;
};

const string& test::getCode() const
{
    return code;
}
const unsigned int test::getDigit() const
{
    return digit;
}
void test::setCode(const string &temp, int num) 
{
    code[num] = temp[num];  
}
void test::setDigit(const int &num)
{
    digit = num;
}


int main()
{
    string contents = "dfskr-123";

    test aisbn;
    list<test> simul;
    list<test>::iterator testitr;
    testitr = simul.begin();
    int count = 0;

    cout << contents << '\n';
    aisbn.setCode(contents, count);
    aisbn.setDigit(count);
    simul.push_back(aisbn);
    count++;

    /*for(; testitr !=simul.end(); simul++)
    {
        cout << testitr->getCode() << "\n";
    }*/

}
```

Comment: Works fi9 for me. http://ideone.com/rWdFQQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that when this statement executes:

```
 code[num] = temp[num];
```

both `code` and `temp` are at least of size `num + 1`.

Comment: void test::setCode(const string &temp, int num) 
 {
  if(num > 1)
  {
   code[num] = temp[num];
  }
 }

Comment: That wouldn't help, I don't think so. What you can do is you can `if (code.size() <= num) code.resize(num + 1);` before the assigment 'code[num] = temp[num]'. That should fix the problem you are facing now; I don't know if this will make your program bahaving correctly, though, I haven't really tried to understand the whole program.

Comment: Good! I'm glad I could help. If this is working for you, then do you mind marking my answer as correct? Thanks!

Comment: that's what i meant :) i just did for u

Comment: Can I ask one more? to avoid core getting dumped, im likely to reset setDigit() like setCode() as well

Comment: Where do you get core dump?

Comment: setDigit() it also need to be resized i guess

Comment: I really don't see how you could get a core dump in your setDigit function

Answer (score 2):

When you create an instance of the `test` class, the string inside it is empty. This means that whenever you do e.g. `code[something]` you will be out of range. It doesn't matter what the index is.

You either need to set the string to a certain length from the start, and make sure that the index is within the range. Or to make sure that the index is within range by dynamically extending the string when needed.